# Is it really possible to protect a connection string in app. config?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, security

We want to protect the login information that is used to connect to our SQL Server database from a .NET windows application.

This information is stored as a connection string in an `app.config` file on the client PC.

Almost everywhere it is suggested you encrypt your connection string using

```
(ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings").ProtectSection();
```

However, a malicious user that wants your database password, could just copy the encrypted config file, use it with it's own application, and call

```
(ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings").UnprotectSection();
```

This will decrypt the connection string back to plain text.

Is there any way to really protect a database password in a .NET application that is stored on a user's PC?

**EDIT**: to further clarify the situation, we are indeed talking about a malicious user (read: competitor) that has access to the same PC and wants the password.

As a secondary measure, we first encrypt the password ourselves, save it to `app.config` and then call `ProtectSection()`. This will make `Unprotect()` output the encrypted password. But the user will still be able to decompile our code and figure out our encryption key and algorithm that is used...

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: But that malicious user will have to run under account which encrypted this section. If things are so bad that attacker got access to that account - there is not much you can do. On the other hand if he just stolen this file - he won't be able to decrypt it.

Comment: This is one reason why Microsoft recommends using windows authentication instead of sql logins.

Comment: @Crowcoder which wouldn't help if one uses anything else than SQL Server

Comment: Note, if a competitor wants the connection string and has access to the same computer as your program they could easily attach a debugger put a breakpoint inside SqlConnection's constructor and just read the decrypted value from there.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser thanks for the tip. While I don't know what their connection strings look like, MySQL and Oracle also support windows authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a malicious user that wants your database password, could just copy the encrypted config file, use it with it's own application

This wouldn't work, unless the malicious user runs on the same computer, or has access to the encryption keys of your [Protected Configuration Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2.aspx).

This is a reasonably strong protection, but if we suppose that web.config could be stolen, we must also suppose that the private key file could be stolen as well. Hence, protected option is "more secure" only in the sense that a kid next door would have harder time breaking it.

If your RDBMS is SQL Server, you could use its [Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) feature to avoid storing, and even creating, login credentials for the RDBMS.

Comment: But as far as I remember, option used in question will encrypt with key specific to current user, not to current machine. So malicious user should not only be able to access the same machine, but also under the same user as config was encrypted under.

Answer (score 1):

All encryption uses a key to encrypt, and you need that key to decrypt.

[The documentation of `ProtectSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection?view=netframework-4.7.1) shows that it takes a parameter that specifies the encryption method. Two are mentioned in that article: [`DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.dpapiprotectedconfigurationprovider?view=netframework-4.7.1) and [`RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider?view=netframework-4.7.1).

`Dpapi` is machine-specific or user-specific (can only be decrypted on the same computer or by the same user). `Rsa` allows for a shared key that can be used on other computers, but you must actually have the key to decrypt.

So no, no one can just steal the .config file and call `UnprotectSection()` and expect it to work.